# Kth element in two sorted arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Given two sorted arrays nums1 and nums2 of size m and n respectively and an int k. Find the k-th largest element of these arrays.
Note that it is the k-th largest element in the sorted order, not the k-th distinct element.

Example 1:

Input: nums1 = [-2, -1, 3, 5, 6, 8], nums2 = [0, 1, 2, 5, 9], k = 4
Output: 5
Explanation: Union of above arrays will be [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9] and the 4th largest element is 5.
Example 2:

Input: nums1 = [2, 4], nums2 = [6], k = 1
Output: 6
Explanation: union of above arrays will be [2, 4, 6] and the 1st largest element is 6.
You may assume k is always valid, 1 ≤ k ≤ m + n.

The code is like this I found on internet

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findKthSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2, int K) {
        int n = nums1.size(), m = nums2.size();
        // We want the greater array
        if(n<m){
            return findKthSortedArrays(nums2, nums1, K);
        }

    // n is always>=m
    int lt = max(0,K-m), rt = min(K,n);
    // lt: put all element in B. (K-m in A, in case K>=m else 0)
    // rt: put all in element in A .
    while(lt<=rt){
        int partX = (lt+rt)/2;
        int y = K - partX;
    
        int maxLeftX = (partX-1>=0 ? nums1[partX-1] : INT_MIN);
        int minRightX = (partX<n ? nums1[partX] : INT_MAX);

        int maxLeftY = (y-1>=0 ? nums2[y-1] : INT_MIN); 
        int minRightY = (y<m ? nums2[y] : INT_MAX);

        if(maxLeftX<=minRightY && maxLeftY<=minRightX){
            return max(maxLeftX, maxLeftY);
        }else if(maxLeftX>minRightY){
            rt = partX-1;
        }else{
            lt = partX+1;
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
};
```

Can someone please help, why we have taken lt = max(0,K-m) and rt = min(K,n).

Comment: Please add a `tag` for the language you are using i.e. `C++`

Comment: no matter whatever language you are using. you are approach should be,
take two array, and merge them. and sort them and then create a `SET`, which will remove duplicates and then convert it back to simple array then get your k'th largest element by arr[k]

Comment: Thank you @J'e , I have made the changes

Comment: Thankx for the suggestion @ShivaSai but it need to be done in logarithmic time only

Comment: @ShivaSai If you remove the duplicates, `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9]` will become `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]` and `k = 5` would return `3` instead of `5`

Comment: @shikhameena Does the code in your question actually work? it gives me `1` for the first example you gave and `2` for the second example.

Answer (score 0):

**Integrate solution:**

I guess you are working on a really hard problem in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/.
And there are several good video explanations available on youtube:

1. Tushar, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPFhl65R7ww
2. HuaHua, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB9IcSCDQ9k

**Answer to your concern:**

The naive solution of this problem would be simply merge two sorted arrays and get the `K`th element, which is of `o(m+n)` complexity.

Given the keyword sorted and initial linear complexity, it is reasonable to search for a log complexity algorithms, `o(log(max(m+n)))`. The basic idea is: we can do binary search for the longer array! And the index in the shorter array is automatically identified.

To be more specific:

> There are totally `K-1` elements before (smaller that or equal to) the `K`th element.

The **`K-1` elements** come from either array `num1` or array `num2`.

> Let `a` and `b` denote the number of elements smaller than the target (`K`th element) in each array. `a+1` is the position of `K`th element if it exists in array `num1`.

Then we have `a+b=K-1`, where `0<=a<n` and `0<=b<m`, such that

`a=K-1-b`.

We can directly set `lt=0` and `rt=n` and do binary search for array `num1`. If we check more details, we can find that `a` shall be greater than `0` if `n<K`, the minimum possible left border of `a` is `K-m-1`, corresponding to `a=K-m-1`, `b=m`.
The minimum target position is `a+1`, so we have `lt = max(0,K-m)`. Similarly, we have `rt = min(K,n)`.

**Illustration:**

num1: ----&++++

num2: -----+++

Let `&` be the target, `-` be the elements smaller than the target, `+` be the greater elenents.

**Notice:**

1. As long as you come up with an solution of log complexity, you will be treated as a qualified problem solver. Compared with the efforts of reducing complexity from `o(n+m)` to `o(log(max(n, m)))`,  the tricks of `lt = max(0,K-m)` and `rt = min(K,n)` is not so important. Be free to neglect this trick **the first time** you come into this problem and grasp the core idea of binary search.
2. Carefully handle the edge cases, e.g., even/odd and so on.